# Get MySQL output in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, grep, output

In my bash file I have the following

```
result=$(mysql --login-path=remote_user --database=mydatabase < "import.sql");
echo $result;
```

I am trying to capture the output so that if it errors I can email myself

When I run the command I get

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 1:....
```

But $result is always empty so how can I assign / capture the error so that I can then use this in the email

Note: I have enforced the error so that I can test

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work for anyone else who has this issue

```
        resultfile="result.txt";
        result=$(mysql --login-path=remote_user --database=mydatabase < "import.sql"  2>&1 ) || echo $result > $resultfile
        if [ -f $resultfile ]; then
            echo "DO SOMETHINNG"
        fi
```